# (Python) How can I split a column with both date and time (e.g. 2019-07-02 00:12:32 UTC) into two separate columns?

Tags: python

I have a table with 8 columns and 40,000 rows, the following table (DF700) is a small section of the entire table. I need to split the 'sdk_ts' column so that the date and time are separate and the 'UTC' is removed from all rows.

```
            sdk_ts                             y       z 

0   2019-07-02 00:12:32 UTC                  3.455   4.555
1   2019-07-02 00:12:32 UTC                  4.567   6.897
2   2019-07-02 00:12:32 UTC                  9.304   0.440    : : : 
3   2019-07-02 00:12:59.6 UTC                8.909   0.405
4   2019-07-02 00:12:34.789 UTC              10.30   2.344
                                 :
                                 :
```

I've attempted the following code:

```
DF800 = DF700['sdk_ts'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
```

However, the result is:

```
         0          1
0   2019-07-02  00:12:32 UTC
1   2019-07-02  00:12:32 UTC
2   2019-07-02  00:12:32 UTC
3   2019-07-02  00:12:59.6 UTC
4   2019-07-02  00:12:34.789 UTC
5   2019-07-02  00:12:35.048 UTC
```

Is there another way I can achieve this goal? Splitting the date and time, getting rid of 'UTC' in all rows and making sure that the other columns are still on the table.

Comment: I practically never used pandas but in python the method to remove characters from a string is called `strip` and googling `pandas str strip` leads me [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html). Did you try `DF700['sdk_ts'].str.strip(' UTC')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest converting the 'sdk_ts' column to datetime format, so you can easily extract date and time from it.

Here is the code:

```
df['sdk_ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sdk_ts'])
df['date'] = df['sdk_ts'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['sdk_ts'].dt.time
```

Answer (score 0):

just use [`strip(' UTC')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.strip.html) to get rid of it before splitting, like this:

```py
DF800 = DF700['sdk_ts'].str.strip(' UTC').str.split(n=1, expand=True)
```

Full example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

DF700 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
            sdk_ts                             y       z 

0   2019-07-02 00:12:32 UTC                  3.455   4.555
1   2019-07-02 00:12:32 UTC                  4.567   6.897
2   2019-07-02 00:12:32 UTC                  9.304   0.440 
3   2019-07-02 00:12:59.6 UTC                8.909   0.405
4   2019-07-02 00:12:34.789 UTC              10.30   2.344"""), sep="\s\s+")

DF800 = DF700['sdk_ts'].str.strip(' UTC').str.split(n=1, expand=True)
print(DF800)
```

Output:

```
            0             1
0  2019-07-02      00:12:32
1  2019-07-02      00:12:32
2  2019-07-02      00:12:32
3  2019-07-02    00:12:59.6
4  2019-07-02  00:12:34.789
```